# How can I apply a function to a single row or column of a matrix using numpy and python

Tags: python, numpy

I am learning numpy and using python and asking for help. I would like to sort a SINGLE row or column as a learning experience. Looking through their docs i see apply_along_axis but there isnt a parameter in their docs on how to indicate a splice/selector in choosing which rows or columns to apply it to.

I only want the second row to be sorted.
Here is my code so far...

```
import numpy as np
A = [29,-11,10,-160,61,-55,55,-21,19]
A = np.asarray(A)
A = np.reshape(A, (3,-1))
np.apply_along_axis(func1d=sorted, axis=1, arr=A) #this line is not correct
```

Starting with the following array...

```
array([[  29,  -11,   10],
       [-160,   61,  -55],
       [  55,  -21,   19]])
```

I would like to see the following output...

```
array([[ 29,   -11,   10],
       [-160,  -55,   61],
       [ 55,   -21,   19]])
```

Comment: Just select the row and sort in place : `A[1].sort()`?

Comment: I also want to be able to apply lambda functions to the row like lambda x:x+1  . i didnt realize sort in my example would cause a conflict in the question.

Answer (score 4):

There's an inplace sort method.

```
In [75]: A=np.array(A).reshape(3,-1)
In [76]: A
Out[76]: 
array([[  29,  -11,   10],
       [-160,   61,  -55],
       [  55,  -21,   19]])
In [77]: A[1,:].sort()
In [78]: A
Out[78]: 
array([[  29,  -11,   10],
       [-160,  -55,   61],
       [  55,  -21,   19]])
```

I just took a guess that it would work on a single row of the array, and tried.  It appears to work.  (I overlooked Divakar's comment).

`apply_along...` and `apply_over...` are convenience functions that make it easier (not faster) to iterate over one or more dimensions, and over kill in a case like this.

It may be easier to understand this with the `np.sort` function:

```
In [85]: np.sort(A[1,:])
Out[85]: array([-160,  -55,   61])
```

the function returns a copy of the row that is sorted; we can then write it back to `A` with:

```
In [86]: A[1,:]=np.sort(A[1,:])
```

`numpy` has its own sorting methods, so usually we don't need to use the general Python list versions, such as `sorted`.  However this works: `A[1,:]=sorted(A[1,:])`.